# akka http custom nested directives

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm trying to nest existing akka http (version 10) directives to create my own custom directives. I'm having issues with things like this:

```
def echoHeaderDirective: Directive0 = optionalHeaderValueByName("X-Echo-Header") {
    case Some(value) => respondWithHeader(RawHeader("X-Echo-Header", value))
    case _ => pass
}
```

The type being returned from the match is `Directive0`, but I get this error from IDEA

> Expression of type Directive0 doesn't conform to expected type Route

and this error from the compiler

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive0
[error]     (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[Unit]
[error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
[error]     case Some(value) => respondWithHeader(RawHeader("X-Echo-Header", value))
```

is it possible to create custom directives in this style (nesting), and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially applying the `Directive`s by nesting them, as you would do to form your `Route`. And indeed, the final nesting level is expecting a `Route` (which is an alias for `RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult]`, as per SBT's complaint).

What you want to do is to *transform* `Directive`s into other `Directive`s, and to do so you should use `map`/`flatMap` functions. Example below:

```
  def echoHeaderDirective: Directive0 = optionalHeaderValueByName("X-Echo-Header") flatMap {
    case Some(value) => respondWithHeader(RawHeader("X-Echo-Header", value))
    case _ => pass
  }
```

More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/custom-directives.html#transforming-directives).

Comment: ah perfect thank you.
for some reason I had read that page earlier and somehow completely missed flatMap

Comment: Seems like now this method called `tflatMap` for some reason